# VBA auto increament number

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add an auto incrementing number to the end of a value for each row of information returned.

Here is what I have. I want to have J1.1 for the first row and then J1.2, J1.3, etc.

```
' J1 Bars
For CurCol = 2 To LastCol
If .Cells(22, CurCol).Value = "" Then
    ' Do Nothing
Else
    DestRow = Sheets("Barlist").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'Quantity
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("A" & DestRow).Value = "1"
    'Bar Size
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("B" & DestRow).Value = .Range("B16")
    'Bar Mark
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("D" & DestRow).Value = "J1.1"
    'Shape
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("E" & DestRow).Value = "17"
    'B Dimension
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("G" & DestRow).Value = .Range("C20")
    'C Dimension
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("H" & DestRow).Value = .Cells(22, CurCol).Value
End If
Next CurCol
```

Comment: You can't concatenate the row number to the end of the text?

Comment: Do 1,2,3.. represent row numbers in J1.1,J1.2,J1.3.. or just a series of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
' J1 Bars
' Define variable to count rows?
Dim rowCounter as Integer
rowCounter = 0
For CurCol = 2 To LastCol
If .Cells(22, CurCol).Value = "" Then
    ' Do Nothing
Else
    DestRow = Sheets("Barlist").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'Quantity
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("A" & DestRow).Value = "1"
    'Bar Size
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("B" & DestRow).Value = .Range("B16")
    'increment row counter
    rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    'Bar Mark with incremented row counter
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("D" & DestRow).Value = "J1." & rowCounter
    'Shape
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("E" & DestRow).Value = "17"
    'B Dimension
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("G" & DestRow).Value = .Range("C20")
    'C Dimension
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("H" & DestRow).Value = .Cells(22, CurCol).Value
End If
Next CurCol
```